# Continue looping over submodules with the "git submodule foreach" command after a non-zero exit

Tags: git, bash, git-submodules

I have a project that contains many submodules. I want to loop over each submodule with the following command:

`git submodule foreach npm install`

And I want the script to continue looping over each submodule even if one submodule returns an error (non zero return code). Currently, a non-zero return code from running this command in any submodule will cause git to stop looping over the remaining submodules.

Any recommendations on how to accomplish this?

Comment: git submodule foreach 'yarn'

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Just make your command always return a `0` code like so:

```
git submodule foreach 'npm install || :'
```

This is taken from the manual: `git help submodule`:

```
   foreach
       Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.
       The command has access to the variables $name, $path, $sha1 and
       $toplevel: $name is the name of the relevant submodule section in
       .gitmodules, $path is the name of the submodule directory relative
       to the superproject, $sha1 is the commit as recorded in the
       superproject, and $toplevel is the absolute path to the top-level
       of the superproject. Any submodules defined in the superproject but
       not checked out are ignored by this command. Unless given --quiet,
       foreach prints the name of each submodule before evaluating the
       command. If --recursive is given, submodules are traversed
       recursively (i.e. the given shell command is evaluated in nested
       submodules as well). A non-zero return from the command in any
       submodule causes the processing to terminate. This can be
       overridden by adding || : to the end of the command.

       As an example, git submodule foreach 'echo $path `git rev-parse
       HEAD`' will show the path and currently checked out commit for each
       submodule.
```

The command `:` from `help :` in `bash`:

```
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

*Always succeeds* `:)`

Comment: `git submodule foreach 'npm install || true'` would do the same.

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows. Was supposed to? Even using bash the \`<command>\` only try to execute the first one and breaks anyway.

Comment: @MarceloFilho: Try using the git bash.

Comment: Using git bash @MaBe... :/

Comment: @MarceloFilho: please open a new question, describing the problem (so that it is reproducible by everybody), and link this question.

Comment: On Mac use " instead of '

Comment: Using an EC2 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, `|| true` failed for me, but `|| :` worked like a charm...  Thank you @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 5):

In **windows** batch, you can set the return code to 0 by adding an ampersand and another command that does nothing:

```
git submodule foreach "npm install & echo done"
```

edit: originally the answer was using a semicolon to do this, which was incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, that's the part that the Git docs completely ignore: non-POSIX shells. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could see this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641469/list-submodules-in-a-git-repository).

I don't use GIT, but if you can locate the .gitmodules files, it may be easy to loop for each submodules :

```
<command to find all of your submodules>|while read; do
    # ... (default use $REPLY as an item)
done
```

Or :

```
while read; do
    # ...
done <<< "$(command to find all of your submodules)"
```

See this [reminder on how to read a command output with a loop in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361#19607361).

Comment: Please don't "parse" `.gitmodules` using shell ... there's a way to do it and that's: `git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp <regexp>` ... which could indeed be piped into while then.

Comment: @0xC0000022L this answer is +10 years old ;) (since, I became very used to use git)...