# Differences between git submodule and subtree

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

What are the conceptual differences between using git submodule and subtree?

What are the typical scenarios for each?

Comment: This may not answer all your questions but is interesting reading on the subject: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Comment: Similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svnexternals-equivalent-in-git/18088319#18088319

Comment: "Alternatives to Git Submodules?
": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500524/alternatives-to-git-submodules

Answer (score 248, accepted):

- **submodule** is a better fit for [component-based development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/933735/6309), where your main project depends on a fixed version of another component (repo).
  You keep only references in your parent repo (**[gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

> What if I want the links to always point to the HEAD of the external repo?

You can make a submodule to follow the HEAD of a branch of a submodule remote repo, with:

o [`git submodule add -b <branch> <repository> [<path>]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309). (to specify a branch to follow)
o `git submodule update --remote` which will update the content of the submodule to the latest HEAD from `<repository>/<branch>`, by default `origin/master`. Your main project will still track the hashes of the HEAD of the submodule even if `--remote` is used though.

---

- **subtree** is more like a [system-based development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769941/6309), where your all repo contains everything at once, and you can modify any part.
  [See an example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309).

Plus, as noted by [philb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6026237/philb) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769820/differences-between-git-submodule-and-subtree#comment120799100_31770147), [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh) is a `contrib/`, as opposed to `git submodule` (core command)

Comment: your answer seems to go against the voted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443627/force-git-submodule-to-always-stay-current

Comment: @NathanH this (the possibility to track HEAD) has been added a year later (March 2013, git 1.8.2: https://github.com/git/git/blob/efc8a625e9b03e6f8ceed37ccd4b9167a7447e31/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L186-L188)

Comment: I see the submodule followship behavior is also mentioned in [your other anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/1509695). In that case I think you mean to say that always pointing to the HEAD of a submodule is accomplished by using both `add -b` and `--remote` thereafter on the update commands, as per the [submodule update documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). In that case, is the `-b` really still required for following HEAD of master?

Comment: @matt the `-b` is used to generate the right .gitmodule metadata for the submodule (it is equivalent to a `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>`).

Comment: Then it has little to do with enabling `--remote` - `--remote` works also if `-b` hasn't been used on `add`. In both cases the update will cause a commit in the parent repo housing the submodule, so the links do not really "always point to the HEAD" in a very automatic way.... either I didn't get it, or that claim better be removed from the original answer (?)

Comment: @matt sure, `--remote` will work without `-b`, because it will default to `origin/master`. But with or without `-b`, a submodule never follows "automatically" a branch, as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309. It checks out the SHA1 memorized in the gitlink, and then updtate its content if you do a `git submodule update --remote`.

Comment: ([New related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418718/updating-submodules-without-committing-their-update))

Comment: another point that might be useful: `git submodule` is a "core" Git command, it's part of the Git codebase. `git subtree` is in the "contrib" directory, it's not installed by Git's Makefile (though some distros do ship it), so it's less developed and less maintained.

Comment: @philb Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: "HEAD" of a branch is nonsensical. It should be "You can make a submodule to follow a branch of a submodule remote repo...".

Answer (score 475):

submodule is link;

subtree is copy

Comment: My two cents: "copy" -> merge.

Answer (score 165):

The conceptual difference is:

With **git submodules** you typically want to separate a large repository into smaller ones. The way of referencing a submodule is *maven-style* - you are referencing a single commit from the other (submodule) repository. If you need a change within the submodule you have to make a commit/push within the submodule, then reference the new commit in the main repository and then commit/push the changed reference of the main repository. That way you have to have access to both repositories for the complete build.

With **git subtree** you integrate another repository in yours, including its history. So after integrating it, the size of your repository is probably bigger (so this is no strategy to keep repositories smaller).
After the integration there is no connection to the other repository, and you don't need access to it unless you want to get an update. So this strategy is more for code and history reuse - I personally don't use it.

Comment: But with `git subtree` you still can also push - if you wanted - right?

Comment: @lxx If you know the repository URL…

Comment: @FranklinYu Why would he not know that? can't get that info from the local git meta data?

Comment: @adi518 Yes, if you are the one who created the subtree. However, if you pushed your repository to GitHub and others clone it down, I don’t think he/she automatically knows the subtree URL.

Comment: @NiklasP - can you elaborate on "reference the new commit in the main repository"?  That's the one step I'm not clear on how to execute and therefore "changed reference" isn't something I understand either.

Comment: "If you need a change within the submodule you have to make a commit/push within the submodule, then reference the new commit in the main repository and then commit/push the changed reference of the main repository."

But the main repo can track a branch of the submodule, right?  So in that case the main repo wouldn't need to do anything to use the updated code?

Answer (score 31):

**sub-module**
pushing a main repo to a remote doesn't push sub-module's files

**sub-tree**
pushing a main repo to remote pushes sub-tree's files

Comment: "pushing a main repo to remote pushes sub-tree's files" No, it doesn't.

Comment: @JBramble I should probably mention that it's done with the SourceTree app eg: `git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags production refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to think of subtrees and submodules is that a subtree is a copy of a repository that is pulled into a parent repository while a submodule is a pointer to a specific commit or branch in another repository.

Comment: submodules can now track particular branches as of git 1.8.2: https://www.activestate.com/blog/getting-git-submodule-track-branch/

Answer (score 6):

[[Git Submodule - Atlassian]](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule)

**Git submodule** is useful when you want to keep the embedded repository's commit history separate from the main repository. However, using submodules can be complex and difficult to manage, especially when you need to update the embedded repository.

[[Git Subtree and comparison with Submodule - Atlassian]](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree)

**Git subtree** is a solution that allows merging one repository into another as a subdirectory, but keeping the entire commit history. It is useful when you want to share a set of files between different projects without the need to maintain a separate repository. Using a subtree is simpler than using a submodule and is generally easier to manage.

In short, if you need to keep the shared repository's commit history separate from the main repository, git submodule might be the best choice. If you need to share a set of files between different projects without the need to maintain a separate repository, git subtree might be the best choice.

---

### Get/Update Workflow Comparison

Let's compare the commands for sending and receiving updates:

**1. Submodule**

```
#push updates:
cd path/to/submodule
1. git add .
2. git commit -m "Submodule Update"
3. git push origin master
cd ..
4. git add submodule
5. git commit -m "Submodule ref update"
6. git push origin master
# >Needs to be in this order! Easy to get trouble<

#pull:
git submodule update --remote
```

---

**2. Subtree**

```
#push updates:
cd path/to/shared/repo
1. git add .
2. git commit -m "Subtree update"
3. git push origin master
#then
4. git subtree push --prefix=path/to/shared/repo shared-repo master

#pull:
git subtree pull --prefix=path/to/shared/repo shared-repo master
```

Answer (score 0):

> What are the conceptual differences between using git submodule and subtree?

Both submodule and subtree are ways to embed another Git repository into a Git repository. However, submodule is reference-based and subtree is copy-based.

> What are the typical scenarios for each?

Let's say you need to embed repository A into your project B:

- If A is stable (i.e., the referenced repository will not be deleted or moved) and you don't need to change A frequently during the development of B, then a submodule is better.
- If B does not need to update A frequently, or if A needs to be changed frequently during the development of B, then a subtree is better.