# Gitflow for projects depending on other repos?

Tags: git, git-flow

In my projects, I used 3rd party git repo as libraries. And I add them in my .gitignore list so that I can pull the libraries separately. Is there a way to bind certain commit in the branch of my project to a certain commit in the 3rd party library?

Comment: That sounds like a use case for submodules.  Or subtrees possibly.  I've seen people hate on both, so you might want to google the documentation for each and see which looks more suitable for you

Comment: Yeah, I also have heard submodule can be very complicated, so I tried to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding a specific commit to a Git repo is more for submodule than subtree: I have illustrated the [differences between the two here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770147/6309).

So add your third-party library repo to your current repo

```
git submodule add /url/to/library library
```

Then checkout the exact commit you want

```
cd library
git checkout <SHA1>
```

Finally, go back to the main repo and record the new **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the main repo)

```
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "new library SHA1"
```