# Two projects share same entities - how to maintain code?

Tags: symfony, git-submodules

We have a project broken in two parts - API and Frontend.
Both are written in Symfony 3.4 and both are in different servers as well as git repositories.
As you may already know, Symfony uses bundles, with every bundle having it's own Entities.
Both of our project use the same Entities from bundles, plus the frontend one has extras.

At the moment, to maintain the entities it's somewhat hard since every change we do in one of the Entities must be aligned with the other project's entities.

I was thinking to use submodules feature from git to keep them both up-to-date, but then, what about the other folders inside the bundles? Like Services and Controllers? I just want to keep track of Entities so when we make a change both projects (or whoever) will be able to have those without us, having to copy-paste stuff.

What are you thinking and what are you suggesting?

Here's an example of the structure. I hope it's readable

```
Project A          Project B
-Bundle 1          -Bundle 1
---Entities        --- Entities

-Bundle 2          -Bundle 2
---Entities        ---Entities
---Services

-Bundle 3          -Bundle 3
---Entities        ---Entities
                   ---Services

                   -Bundle 4
```

Comment: Pleas, do not downvote unless you state why you did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: A workaround could be multi-kernels approach https://github.com/yceruto/symfony-skeleton-vkernel

Comment: One thing to consider is that entities do not have to be in a Symfony bundle.  They can be off in their own little shared package and you can then configure your entity managers to use them.  And as far as your down vote request, I'd suggest staying away from oceans as you may find yourself trying to stop the tide from coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some options, you could use you're `API` to get data on your `Frontend` meaning you would only need your entities in your`API` bundle.

Or you could have your entities in a third project being only one bundle with entities. Bundle that you would add to the two other projects with `Composer`

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package

Comment: Yep, the way it's to make the calls to API and the API to be able to communicate with Entities. But some times it's faster not make the call and have the Frontend handle some Entities too.   
I was thinking about the composer, but wouldnt that mean i have to extend the Bundles from vendor ?

Comment: Yes that's it your entities would be in the vendor in both project

Comment: We went with the composer "idea" so i'm marking this as a correct/helpful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Move entities and/or shared parts inside another repository and consider start using git submodules or git subtree. Using this trick you can add a git repository inside another. And you can also update shared content committing and pushing from the submodule.

- [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)
- [difference between submodules and subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769820/differences-between-git-submodule-and-subtree)
- [subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree)