# Add multiple projects under one Git repository using Git tools - Submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, multiple-projects

i would like to add multiple projects under a single Git repository using Git tools - submodules. At present i have a Git repository that contains only one project. Now, i need to add another different project also under the same repository such both are at the same level

Can you please provide me a solution to add new project to existing Git repository such that all my projects are present under the same level?

Comment: Impossible. Every Git repository is a directory tree. A second repository can be in a subdirectory but cannot be at the same level.

Comment: Identical to your earlier https://stackoverflow.com/q/62450011/341994? Did you think the answer would be different if you ask it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add multiple projects into one Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450011/add-multiple-projects-into-one-git-repository)