# How to handle my git project using the files of another much more active github project?

Tags: git, github

I'm about to start a git project that uses a lot of code and data from another open source project, and basically provides another "view" to the data. It will be hosted separately. I will need to pull upstream changes to both code and data.

What is a proper and useful way of handling this in git? I don't think I can simply fork the original project and keep pulling upstream changes, as it litters the root directory too much and I need to "encapsulate" it.

(The original project manager approves of my idea but is not interested in having it as part of their repo.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a submodule or a subrepo, choose what fits your needs. In case of subrepo, basically you maintain a copy of the other repo in one of the folders inside your repo.

Learn about the [differences between git submodule and subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769820/differences-between-git-submodule-and-subtree).

Comment: Thank you. It seems that Github doesn't support subrepos, do you know if that's right?

Comment: I've found something that might help in case you would go with submodules on github:
https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255
I haven't tried it myself, but the comments are promising, so I assume it should work for you too.