# Alternative for git submodules

Tags: git, version-control, dependencies, git-submodules

I often write some libraries for my own usage that I want to use in different projects. I would like to have a possibility to edit the library and make the changes valid in all the projects where the libraries are used. Until now I always had to do copy&paste.

I tried submodules but there seem to be many downfalls according to [git submodules reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Are there better possibilities for this dependency management?
What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Typically you'd use the standard package-management approaches for the particular language you're working in.

Comment: i'm quite a newbie. if i do C what would that be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git subtree or GitSlave as alternatives to Git Submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500524/git-subtree-or-gitslave-as-alternatives-to-git-submodules)

Answer (score 0):

There are two situation to work with libraries for different projects.
Assume the libraries in `repoA`, and `repoB` is one of the project repositories.

#### Situation 1: The libraries only work for you own (only manage libraries in repoA)

You can add the libraries from local `repoA` to local `repoB` directly:

In local `repoB` -> right click the solution for projectB -> Add  -> An existing project -> Add the libraries from local `repoA` to local `repoB` -> commit -> push.

Now no matter where (in local `repoA` or local `repoB`) you changed the libraries, it's actually change the libraries in local `repoA`, So the libraries in local `repoA` and local `repoB` always sync.

#### Situation 2: other developers also need the libraries in projectB (manage libraries both in repoA and repoB)

If other developers also need to use the libraries, you should also manage the libraries in `repoB`. The ways usually used are `git submodule` and `git subtree`.

Since you have already tries submodules, I will only show `git subtree` as below:

- Add the libraries (assume in `master` branch of `repoA`) to `repoB`:

  ```
    git subtree add --prefix=repoB <URL for repoB> master
  ```
- If there has some changes in `repoA`, get the changes from `repoA` to `repoB`:

  ```
    git subtree pull --prefix=repoB <URL for repoB> master
  ```
- If make changes for libraries in `repoB`, to push the changes to `repoA`:

  ```
    git subtree push --prefix=repoB <URL for repoB> master
  ```